# Point Typescript paths to a folder outside of the project folder so it can be shared between projects

Tags: typescript, tsc

I realize the title might sound a little unclear.

I have a project that is split into smaller parts.

> Project
>
> - _ORM
> - admin
> - api

Now, both admin and api need to be able to load modules and models from the '_ORM'. So I figured I'd simply put some paths in the tsconfig, which works, but for some reason the output is structured as follows (this happens when compiling admin, in this example):

> dist
>
> - _ORM
> - admin
> - - src

In this nested src folder are the contents that should be in the root (dist). Any idea on how to properly do this?

Here's the parts of the configuration that are relevant to this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@framework/*": [
        "../../_ORM/framework/*"
      ],
      "@models/*": [
        "../../_ORM/models/*"
      ],
      "@db/*": [
        "../../_ORM/framework/db/*"
      ]
    }
}
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
]
```

I have tried setting rootDirs to include both `../_ORM` and `src', to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you succeed in moving generated files to the root directory, then the `require` (or `import`) with relative paths will fail at runtime.

Comment: A solution is to use distinct npm packages for `_ORM`, `admin` and `api`. However you could keep all the sub-projects in a monorepository, for example with the help of [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/).

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I can't remember to be honest, but I would have updated the post. Sorry!